# How to upload file using Volley library in android?

Tags: android, file, http-post, httprequest, android-volley

I already have a sub class of `Request<JSONObject>` that is used for http post to the server. The problem is, I have no idea on how can I add a parameter for a file. Posting string to the server is easy. but I need to add file as a different parameter. How can I do it?

```
public class AddNewPetRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;

    public AddNewPetRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
                                Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Request.Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public AddNewPetRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                                Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE QUESTION:**
I followed the pattern of one of the answers here in stackoverflow and I came up with this implementation:

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {

private MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private HashMap<String, String> mParams;


public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Response.Listener<String> listener)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
    mListener = listener;

    buildMultipartEntity();
}

private void buildMultipartEntity()
{
    entity.addPart("profile_picture", new FileBody(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/VSCOCam/2015-07-31 11.55.14 1.jpg")));
    try
    {
        entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("15"));
        entity.addPart("name", new StringBody("Bogs"));
        entity.addPart("gender", new StringBody("Male"));
        entity.addPart("date_birth", new StringBody("1999-12-5"));
        entity.addPart("breed", new StringBody("monkey"));
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return entity.getContentType().getValue();
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        entity.writeTo(bos);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}

@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
{
    return Response.success("Uploaded", getCacheEntry());
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response)
{
    mListener.onResponse(response);
   
}
```

When I add this request to my request queue, it responded with a  `com.android.volley.TimeoutError` but if a check the data base, the request  executes and add items to the table but the profile picture upload has only 1 byte of size. another problem, my database item added twice.

Comment: Check out here :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/19981901/4018207

Comment: You can read [my question and answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity). Hope this helps!

Comment: @MamataGelanee how can I get MultipartEntity class? im importing this throug my gradle **compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android'** , version: '4.3.5.1' but it seems that MultipartEntity is still missing.

Comment: @Earwin delos Santos : Try to add this all libraries in gradle ->  apache-mime4j, httpclient, httpcore and httpmime. I think 'MultipartEntity' is in httpmime.

Comment: add this : 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5'

Comment: @MamataGelanee i don't understand why the one who posted the answer said that the volley library is not the right choice for doing this kind of http post

Comment: @ Earwin delos Santos : check performance of both library here :- http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: @ Earwin delos Santos : Actually its a vast topic. Just focus on issue related gradle . later which is better that you can search over google ..!!

Comment: Hi, have you read my comment?

Comment: @MamataGelanee do you know to convert my answer to JSONObject request? because I need to obtain my json response

Comment: @Earwin delos Santos : Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/18073849/4018207

Comment: Please do not edit answers (or even only "solved") into questions. Create your own answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

may this method helps you:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri, String fileName)
{
    String upLoadServerUri = "your_api_url";

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 
    //errMsg=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    if (!sourceFile.isFile())
    {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }
    try {
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        //conn.setRequestProperty("pid", "4");
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);                
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        if(serverResponseCode != 200)
        {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Il y a une erreur l'hors du trasfert de l'image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });  
        }

        //close the streams //
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {  
        // dialog.dismiss();  
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //  dialog.dismiss();  
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context,errMsg+ "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);  
    }
    //  dialog.dismiss();         
    return serverResponseCode;  
}
```