# How to rewrite my multipart post string request to json object request using volley?

Tags: android, request, http-post, android-volley

I have a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262829/how-to-upload-file-using-volley-library-in-android) on stack overflow, and I already solved my problem upon using a multipart post through Volley. The problem is, what I have done is a `String` request and I want it to be change to `JSONObject` request because I needed to catch the server's response.

**UPADATE :** I also tried to change all `Response<String>` to `Response<JSONObject>`

This is my new implementation at my `parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)` method :

```
 @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
    {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately, It started calling the error response method

```
   @Override
   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.i("Error",error.toString());
                        }
```

The error displayed is :

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <div of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 0):

As my answer in your previous question, I suggest that you create a custom request that reponses `NetworkResponse` or `JSONObject` like the following :

**MultipartRequest.java:**

```
class MultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private final Map<String, String> mHeaders;
    private final String mMimeType;
    private final byte[] mMultipartBody;

    public MultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers, String mimeType, byte[] multipartBody, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
        this.mHeaders = headers;
        this.mMimeType = mimeType;
        this.mMultipartBody = multipartBody;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return mMimeType;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mMultipartBody;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }
}
```

Here, you can create a custom `MultipartRequest extends Request<JSONObject>`
Hope this helps!

**UPDATE FOR YOUR COMMENT:**

> I have a multipart entity is already included in apache http component libraries. Is there is any alternatives?

Here is my Request with `HttpEntity` and return a `JSONArray`. I think you can customize to return a `JSONObject` if you like.

```
private void makeJsonArrayRequest(Context context, int method, String url, HttpEntity httpEntity, final VolleyResponseListener listener) {
        JSONObject jsonRequest = null;
        String stringEntity;
        try {
            stringEntity = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            if (stringEntity != null) {
                jsonRequest = new JSONObject(stringEntity);
            }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(method, url, jsonRequest, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                listener.onResponse(jsonArray);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                listener.onError(getErrorMessage(error));
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                ...
            }
        };

        // Access the RequestQueue through singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

Comment: the code is too long. I have a multipart entity is already included in apache http component libraries. Is there is any alternatives?

Comment: @EarwindelosSantos: see my updated answer. However, I suggest you use the code without using HttpEntity because of its deprecation. Long code is not a very big problem :)

Comment: i tried to edit all `Response<String>` to `Response<JSONObject>` but It start calling the error response method. this is the error `com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <div of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: I also change my implement at `parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)` this is my new implementation `try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }`

Comment: @EarwindelosSantos: are you sure the response is a valid JSONObject? Try `parseNetworkResponse` and post your debug values and/or logcat for more information

Comment: @EarwindelosSantos: refer to [this document for JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29) `source - A string beginning with { (left brace) and ending with } (right brace).`

Comment: the response is a valid json. I tried it on jsonlint.com I think there must be something wrong in my code

Comment: @EarwindelosSantos: check if in your response has `<div ` or not, I think it causes error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88554/discussion-between-earwin-delos-santos-and-bnk).

Comment: do I need to override the getParams() method?

Comment: I already got my response when uploading an image file, but when the server side code checks the file type of the uploaded image, its not `image/jpg` type. the result was `application/octet-stream` type

Comment: For this content type, refer to my answer at the third link in your previous question. "ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/png");". Then you can replace png by jpeg or jpg if you like.

Comment: something weird happened,  not all images or video from my mobile phone is being uploaded. there are few selected images and video  are able to saved in  the server

Comment: Volley is not recommended for large size files or upload too many files

Comment: im not uploading all at once. if that's the case, what you should I do? what alternatives do you have? please reply at the chat.

Comment: Retrofit, OkHttp or HttpUrlConnection...you can try. Sorry, I on holiday with family, cannot chat now

Comment: thank you very much, I think i really should switch http framework.