# How to Upload File with volley in server

Tags: android, android-volley

1. Can convert Pdf or Txt such a image to binary and send ?
2. Can send file without convert to binary and send ? and How to this work!
3. how to can upload 2 or 3 file to server with thread ?

i use `Custommultipart` but i think the better way should be exist.
thak you for helping me !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload file using Volley library in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262829/how-to-upload-file-using-volley-library-in-android)

Comment: You have to convert the file to a byte array. That's how network transfers work.