# How can i upload a file to Kloudless from my android?

Tags: android, android-volley, google-drive-android-api, kloudless

I wanted to upload a file from my android internal storage to Any cloud storage(ex.google drive,One drive etc)since kloudless provides an api to upload file to any cloud storage using accesstoken I wanted to use the same api for uploading the file (https://api.kloudless.com/v1/accounts/accountid+/storage/files/).

I tried it through postman I am able to upload the file[image]

Now I tried through android volley I am able to create the file in the cloud but there is no data inside it. Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b;
TextView TV;
File myFile;
String responseString;
String path;
public String BASE_URL = "https://api.kloudless.com";
private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TV = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    b = findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
    });
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
            // Get the path
            String path = null;
            try {
                path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("TAG", "File Path: " + path);
            try {
                data();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
public void data() throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final String url = BASE_URL + "/v1/accounts/" + "accountid" + "/storage/files/";

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put( "file","somedata");

    JSONObject Body=new JSONObject(params);

    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,Body, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // response
            Log.d("Response", response.toString());
        }
    },
            new ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer Bearerkey");
              params.put("Content-Type", "form-data");
            params.put("X-Kloudless-Metadata", "{\"parent_id\":\"root\",\"name\":\"testdone.txt\"}");
         //   params.put("Content-Length", Space);
            return params;
        }



    };
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Please help me how to send the file in body of my request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the simple solution to upload a file to api

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = BASE_URL + "/v1/accounts/" + "353284419" + "/storage/files/";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer ix7wW4CFJsHxhttg42qsO6HNNRPh06");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            params.put("X-Kloudless-Metadata", "{\"parent_id\":\"root\",\"name\":\"testing uplodes.pdf\"}");
            //      params.put("Content-Length", Space);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
            File f=new File(path);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            try {
                fis.read(bytesArray);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bytesArray;
        };

    };
    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            40000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(postRequest);
   }
```

just convert the file into binary array and send it in the body

Answer (score 1):

I work at Kloudless and while I am not very familiar with the Android Volley, the issue here appears to be that you are setting a JSON body with the incorrect content type. In order to replicate the Postman request, you would need to use a multipart file upload instead, as described here: [How to upload file using Volley library in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262829/how-to-upload-file-using-volley-library-in-android) The file would need to be added to a field called `file`, e.g `entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File("....")));`

In order for there to be more efficient handling on the server side (for larger files), the request performed should instead include the binary file contents in the request body and have the header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. Based on some cursory searching, it seems like the Volley library doesn't make that very easy so it might be best to try a different library.

Comment: @dthorrman Can you just give me a solution how to do it with http async post request.